# Ubuntu warning. W: Duplicate sources.list entry

Tags: ubuntu, apt, virtualbox

After installing Oracle VirtualBox, when I do `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following warning

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ raring/contrib i386
Packages
(/var/lib/apt/lists/download.virtualbox.org_virtualbox_debian_dists_raring_contrib_binary-i386_Packages)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please post the output of `grep virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: alexkd@Active-pc:~$ grep virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d
`/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian raring contrib
grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d: its directory`

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `*`, I meant `grep virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`. Also, please [edit] your question to add new information and leave a comment mentioning me (@terdon) so I will be notified.

Comment: @AlexKurmaev it's best to add this information directly in your answer, with the edit button (which is right below the tags). this is because comments are considered second-class citizens on Stack Exchange, and so aren't guaranteed to stick around. also, welcome to Stack Exchange! (edit: didn't realize terdon had already mentioned that.)

Answer (score 1):

I think VirtualBox create a new list folder so you can remove it using

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list~
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```